# How to fill or stretch blocks using Freewall.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, stretch

I am using freewall.js for my latest website.
Found from http://vnjs.net/www/project/freewall/
when i checking in large screen, it shows some blank area, how to solve this? please check my screenshot .
[image]

Comment: Doesnt look like the library will adjust to fill the screen from first look. Could dynamically create more content when it detects a larger screen?

Comment: Hi Dave Walker, if the content is less ?

Comment: As I said above it doesn't look like the library will adjust. Otherwise for example if you had one block it would stretch it to fill the entire screen.